# How do I effectively store data relating to the DOM without putting it in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I create a table that represents a database table, and I want to have functions like add/edit/delete, and I am using jquery, how can i avoid having to make 3-4 .parent() calls to get the table data I need? In this scenario I am talking about ASC/DESC arrows that allow a user to sort a column. The arrow needs to trigger an AJAX post to PHP, and thus it needs to also send the database table name and often a row id. But apart from attaching this information to every sort arrow, I have to traverse way up the DOM tree and I think that's gotta be the wrong way to do things.

I think this may also all come down to not storing data in the DOM, but I really don't know what the other method is..

**Example**

I use pre-made table templates, such as

```
<table id = "users">
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <div class = "sortingArrows">
          <div class = "sortAsc"></div>
          <div class = "sortDesc"></div>
      </div>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><span name = "user_name"></span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The table gets cloned, and the spans are filled in if they have matching column names. Works fine.

I want to sort the table by user name

```
// This handler is common to all tables
$('.sortAsc').on('click', function(){
     // Better way to avoid excessive parent calls?
    var tableName = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    // Return sorted table
    $.post.....
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest()`

```
var tableName = $(this).closest("table").attr('id');
```

P.S:
`<div class = "sortingArrows">` is an invalid child of `tr`. Use `<td>` or `<th>` (in your specific case)

Comment: Is this an acceptable thing to do, though? Is it not a bad thing to store data in the DOM?

Comment: IMO storing data in the DOM is fine if the data pertains to the actual display of information. In your case, you are cutting corners to speed up a sort operation, which I think is fine. However, if you were to put additional information that might be used for an AJAX call or something, I think you'd be better off maintaining that data in an object.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the part "how can I avoid setting the values in the DOM".   The answer is using a closure pattern, like the one below;

```
var C = (function(){
   var myNodes = {};
   return {
      getNode: function(name) { return myNodes[name];},
      setNode: function(name, value) { myNodes[name] = value; }
   }
})();
```

You can now use the getNode and setNode to set and retrive values without they are exposed in the dom, like;

```
C.setNode('value',7);
C.setNode('xyz', $(this) );

C.getNode('value'); // returns 7
```

Comment: Why not just use an object?

Comment: `C` itself a container object since it contain methods.

Comment: An object already has get and set, this is just a global object.

Comment: Sure, this is just a get/set -- the point is that you can use the closure pattern to create much more functionality beyond the get/set

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking to get the id of the table it is part of?

jQuery provides the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function for this.

```
var tableName = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
```